# как при выборе пароля не заносить значения в input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Просто при выборе оно ставит в инпут 14 шрифт, а после выбора 16 как и нужно

[image: введите сюда fdизображения]

надо так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

То, что у вас называется "оно ставит", это функция автозаполнения, реализованная в браузере. Пока вы только наводите мышку - **в инпуте еще ничего нет**, просто поверх инпута выводится браузерный блок-заглушка; ее размер шрифта зависит от установок пользователя (размера шрифта в браузере и в системе), и повлиять на это вы не сможете никак.

А вот после того как вы выбрали предложенный автозаполнением вариант (кликнули мышью), он подставляется в инпут **и только тогда** вы увидите шрифт в 16 пикселей.

Максимум что вы можете сделать, если вас это так раздражает - отключить автозаполнение для этого инпута вообще атрибутом `autocomplete="off"`.

Comment: а если это логин и пароль?

Comment: а что это  меняет?

Comment: смысл в том если autoComplete="email" на емаил а на пароле autoComplete="new-password", то вылазит выпадающее меню с подсказками которые ты вводил. а на пароле  выподашка с сохраненными паролями и вначале пустые поля. autocomplete="off" вообще не сохраняет по email даже нету выподашки с подсказками вводивыми

Comment: Я знаю, для чего нужно автозаполнение. Я спросил "что это меняет", потому что решил, что вы думаете, что поведение шрифта как-то зависит от предназначения поля. Нет, увы, не зависит. Внешний вид автокомплита, как и тултипа (подсказки при навееднии мышью на элемент с атрибутом `title`) зависит только от настроек браузера и операционки того, кто смотрит.